# how to preload texture atlas to improve performance and reduce lagging? swift, spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, textures

My game lags quite a bit so i am trying to optimise its performance by preloading the textures that i'm using. In the game I am adding new sprites to the scene with a function, so every time the function is called it creates a new texture. When i move the line that creates the texture outside of the function, i get an error (see code below). Does anyone know how i can avoid creating textures every time a function that adds them is called?

```
class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  // i tried to put the "var ball..." line here but it came up as an error when contact had been made
func addBall() {


    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.speed = 1
    var ball = imageLoad(imageNamed: "Ball") // <--- i want to shift this out



    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.name = "ball"

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    ball.physicsBody?.mass = 0.01
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.ballCategory.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.heroCategory.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.heroCategory.rawValue
    ball.setScale(0.75)

    let minX = ball.size.width/2
    let maxX = self.frame.size.width - ball.size.width/2
    let rangeX = maxX - minX
    let position: CGFloat = round(CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX))
    acorn.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height)
    addChild(ball)

    let minDuration = 2
    let maxDuration = 8
    let rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration
    let duration = Int(arc4random()) % Int(rangeDuration) + Int(minDuration)
    var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -acorn.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))

    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

    ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))


}

func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate: CFTimeInterval){
    lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    slowlastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    if (lastYieldTimeInterval>1) {
        lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
        addBall()





    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `imageLoad` does, but here's one way to preload and reuse a texture.

Add the following code to your SKScene subclass

```
let ballTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ball")
```

Modify your `addBall` method to create your ball sprite from a texture by

```
func addBall() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture)
    ...
```

I recommend you create a `performSelector` `SKAction` to add balls at fixed intervals instead of adding them in the `update` method.

Lastly, I suggest you move `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` and `self.physicsWorld.speed = 1` from `addBall` to the `didMoveToView` method, so they aren't called repeatedly whenever you create balls.